# Maven - Запуск java приложения

Tags: java, maven

Привет. В Linux я начинающий...
Есть VDS с Debian, чистый, поставил только Maven и Apache. 
Есть java серверное приложение, которое я запускаю в Maven: mvn exec:java
После разрыва ssh соединения с сервером либо просто долгого ожидания java сервер уже недоступен. 
Запуск через php exec() работает, но это не то, что я хотел.

Вопрос как запустить серверное java приложение в maven чтобы оно работало после перезагрузки например init.d или еще что?

Comment: Вам обязательно использовать именно maven для запуска приложения? Обычно же с помощью maven собирают war или jar, а их запускают с помощью tomcat, например

Comment: @Александр я честно не в курсе как лучше запускать и через что, но запускать надо это - https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio Томкат это лучшее решение для этой задачи?

Comment: @Александр запускать в сервисе нормальный вариант? я имею ввиду закинуть в init.d/startserverscript где будет запускаться jar в сервисе средствами java: java -jar name.jar .....пока это работает, но правильно ли это с точки зрения правильности? или все же лучше лучше использовать специальные для этого средства типа томкат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходим запуск приложения при старте системы - init.d то, что надо. Но обратите внимание на пользователя, от имени которого будет запущен процесс. Запускать приложение от имени root - потенциально опасно для публичного сервера.

Ещё есть утилита [screen](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/screen), которая позволяет "свернуть" запущенное приложение, разорвать ssh соединение, но оставит живым и работоспособным процесс, который был запущен в сеансе. После нового подключения по ssh screen может "развернуть" тот самый процесс.

Если же речь идёт о сервлетах, то предлагаю использовать tomcat или аналоги.

Ещё обращу внимание на то, что мониторинг падения самого приложения не входит в обязанности всего выше описанного, но для этого можно написать отдельный скрипт.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду думать что лучше использовать. Пока поставил cron на скрипт, который запускает в сервисе java приложение(т.е. сервер).